# Mounting SMB Shares in Fstab issues

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

I just upgraded my file server from 16.04 to 20.04 and everything seems to be working except for my SMB mounts on my Ubuntu computer.
I can access the SMB shares on my Windows computer but on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer I can't get the shares mounted in fstab.

If I mount the shares from the command line (command below) it is mounted just fine.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=username,vers=3.0 //192.168.1.116/Share /mnt/Share/
```

However when I try to mount the share in fstab (command below) the smb share is not mounted.

```
//192.168.1.116/Share  /mnt/Share  cifs  credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp  0  0
```

After doing a `sudo mount -a` and trying a `ls` I get:

> ls: cannot access 'Share': Operation not supported

and when I do a `smbclient -L //192.168.1.116` I get:

> protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE

**Update:**

When I do a

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp //192.168.1.116/Share /mnt/Share/
```

The SMB share is mounted properly.

When I do a

```
smbclient -L //192.168.1.116 -d 0
```

I get the same result:

> protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE.

`dmesg -t | grep -e CIFS` returns:

> CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95

When I check dmesg with the debug turned on I get a lot of:

> /build/linux-Dh1oQA/linux-4.4.0/fs/cifs/cifsfs.c: CIFS VFS: in
> cifs_statfs as Xid: 9405245 with uid: 1000

> /build/linux-Dh1oQA/linux-4.4.0/fs/cifs/cifsfs.c: CIFS VFS: leaving
> cifs_statfs (xid = 9405245) rc = -95

> /build/linux-Dh1oQA/linux-4.4.0/fs/cifs/inode.c: CIFS VFS: in
> cifs_revalidate_dentry_attr as Xid: 9405247 with uid: 1000

> /build/linux-Dh1oQA/linux-4.4.0/fs/cifs/inode.c: CIFS VFS: leaving
> cifs_revalidate_dentry_attr (xid = 9405247) rc = -95

Comment: It might be because they've removed SMB1 support, for security reasons. There's a way to re-enable it in /etc/samba/smb.conf, but of course, it's not recommended. I can't speak much about the hows and whys. I do have the smb.conf mods if you require it.

Comment: I thought the vers=3.0 in my fstab was forcing the client to connect using SMB 3 instead on 1?

Comment: Just curious... have you rebooted .116? Are you running Ubuntu on .116 and the client computer? What version Windows? Was this working before you updated the server to 20.04?

Comment: @heynnema .116 has been rebooted a few times. Everything was running just fine before I upgraded. The Samba shares work in Both Win7 and Win10.
Ubuntu 20.04 on .116 and 18.04 on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened but I was able to get this issue resolved.

I decided I'd start over and did a sudo umount /mnt/Share(s). After unmounting each directory I was about to use sudo mount -a and have my mount points in fstab all mount properly.

The clue was in an answer that is no longer available. The answer author (iirc @heynnema) asked me to put `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777` in my fstab for a mount.

Fresh eyes this morning noticed that the directory was highlighted. A quick `ls -l` showed me it was 777 which wasn't right.
I wasn't able to change it by adjusting fstab so I figured I'd start fresh again. Seems it worked this time around.

In the end I added to my;

smb.conf file

```
min client protocol = NT1
max client protocol = SMB3
```

/etc/fstab

```
vers=3.0
```

Even with min client protocol = NT1. The vers=3.0 was required.

Comment: The helpful answer isn't available any more but I summarized what the resolution ended up being.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Your `max client protocol = SMB3` is probably incorrect though, as SMB3 should probably be NT3, or you could probably just leave the entire line out of smb.conf.

Answer (score 2):

Would you try debug for smblient with?

```
smbclient -L //192.168.1.116 -d 0
```

Are you able to mount via the command line using the options and credentials file from fstab?

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp //192.168.1.116/Share /mnt/Share/
```

What are you getting in dmesg for CIFS errors?

```
dmesg -t | grep -e CIFS
```

We can also enable debug of the cifs module.

```
modprobe cifs
echo 'module cifs +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
echo 'file fs/cifs/* +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
echo 7 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI
```

and disable it with.

```
echo 0 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI
```

Check dmesg for the cifs module debug output also.

Comment: When I do a () I get the same result: protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE. 
Using sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp //192.168.1.116/Share /mnt/Share/

Comment: @Havock Did you substitute your real userid for "user" in the above command?

Comment: @heynnema eventually I did :) Even with the proper userid it didn't work